# Allows > character Symfony2 routing

Tags: symfony-2.8

I am using symfony2 fos routing bundle for rest apis end pointd.

I have a url parameter for `{searchTerm}` keyword.

```
https://example.com/api/category/Production > Offices/1
```

And Route defined like this in controller.

```
@Rest\Get("/api/locations/category/{searchTerm}/{pageNumber}", 
requirements={"searchTerm"=".+>"})
```

but it's not working.